# Anyone know a better way do write this login function in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

Hay I was wondering if anyone knew a better way to do this.

```
def login_user(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = User.objects.filter(username=username)

    if user:
        user = user[0]
        if user.password == generate_password(password):
            return HttpResponse("password fine")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("password incorrect")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("no user found by that username")
```

and the generate_password function is just

```
generate_password(string):
    return hashlib.sha224(str(string)).hexdigest()
```

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Your function `generate_password` is misleadingly named, I suggest you call it something like `hash_password`.

Comment: but it generates a password, so generate_password would be a valid name? Its also used in my model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't use [Django auth default views](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) ?

Comment: Prefer to write my own to aid my python learning. I know people say 'don't reinvent the wheel', but i find reinventing it helps a lot when learning!

Comment: This is a wheel you should not be reinventing - at best you will put a lot of effort into something that had already been implemented; at worst you'll waste effort and get it wrong. Why don't you use your time to come up with an awesome Internet site? Solve real problems, not imaginary ones.

Comment: If you want to learn Python better, read the existing contrib.auth code.  It's fine to do this for edification, just not for production code.

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth

Comment: In general I agree with the 'do not reinvent the wheel' principle. That said I worked on a project where it was necessary to record login and logout events in an application log. Since `auth` does not emit any signals or provide any hooks to do this I had to come up with my own mechanism to go about this. There is a ticket open for this: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5612

Answer (score 1):

the only amelioration i see is use get instead of filter (it will save you one line)

```
user = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

Comment: If you do this, remember that you need to catch a `User.DoesNotExist exception` instead of checking `if user`

Comment: can you give an example of how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the level of control you want to have, you'll want to make use of the `authenticate` and maybe `login` functions in `django.contrib.auth`. These are the main functions for accessing authentication. I should stress that you really, really should use these instead of finding the user and checking the password hash manually. There are a number of reasons why:

- they will make use of whatever authentication backend you or someone else in the future have installed
- your version will be far less tested than Django's and is more likely to open security holes
- it's quicker, shorter, more flexible and more readable
- Django's auth app will probably change in the near future, sticking to `authenticate` will help you migrate to the new auth app when it gets written/committed/released

If you do want to rewrite the way a user is found and authenticated, write your own [Authenticate backend](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend), which will be used when you call `authentication` (even in someone else's app, like the admin). This is the only place you should rewrite authentication in Django.

The following examples are from the [Django auth docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#how-to-log-a-user-in).

**1. Checking a user's password:**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
user = authenticate(username='john', password='secret')
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        print "You provided a correct username and password!"
    else:
        print "Your account has been disabled!"
else:
    print "Your username and password were incorrect."
```

**2. Custom authentication backend:**

Here is a backend that uses the same authenticate method as Django's, which you can find at `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyBackend:
  def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
    try:
      user = User.objects.get(username=username)
      if user.check_password(password):
        return user
    except User.DoesNotExist:
      return None

  def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
      return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
      return None
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'd really prefer to use my own system. Can you see any obvious security holes in my code?

Comment: Above is exactly how you would do it. If you want to rewrite the way a user is authenticated, write your own authentication backend. If you do that, Django will use your custom `authenticate` function: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend

It's good design practice to separate the logic of authenticating a user into a separate module/function. Django encourages this by providing the `authenticate` function and allowing you to override its implementation. Please don't do it any other way with Django!

Comment: Not sure about security holes, but: 1) There's an uncaught `KeyError` if `password` or `username` are not passed as GET parameters. 2) An encoding error if password has a character which can't be converted to ascii in `generate_password` 3) you're not taking inactive accounts into consideration 4) I'm not even sure it would work, given that django passwords are stored " *algorithm* `$` *salt* `$` *hash* "  5) any custom backend authentication is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You should download django-registration and go through the code. It manages everything for you, including cleaning the code. Your original code will not handle empty submissions.

http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/